# Dialog does not appear when it's called

Tags: jquery, html

When I click on the anchor

```
<span>Forgot your password? Click <a href="#" id="ForgetPassword">here</a> to retrieve it.</span>
```

I want to show a form in a dialog

```
  <form action="UsersAccountServlet" id="retrievePasswordForm" method="post">
        <label>Email address</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" />
        <input type="submit" name="retrievePassword"/>
         <input type="hidden" name="lang" value="E"/>
         <c:if test="${retrivePassResult != null}">
             <c:out value="${retrivePassResult}"></c:out>
         </c:if>
    </form>
```

I use this jquery script to show the dialog but the **dialog i does not appear**?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ForgetPassword").click(function(){
     alert("here");
     $("#retrievePasswordForm").dialog();

 });
});
```

Comment: Do you have any javascript errors in browser console?

Comment: Does #retrievePasswordForm have display:none at start?

Comment: did u include jquery ui?

Comment: @avall, no but it's not the reason no to show the dialog.

Comment: @shernshiou yes here's it <script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>

Comment: @Alaa i meant jquery ui.. not the base jquery lib

Comment: see this error please "$("#retrievePasswordForm").dialog is not a function" !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/shernshiou/8rVBm/1/
seems working..

did you include jquery ui?

Comment: It seems this is the problem.

Comment: then u need to add the jquery ui css too :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#retrievePasswordForm" ).dialog( "open" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is the same problem when calling content to Fancybox.

You should wrap form with display:none div and then call dialog for form:
And **don't** hide form tag.

```
<div style="display:none">
    <form action="UsersAccountServlet" id="retrievePasswordForm" method="post">
        <label>Email address</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" />
        <input type="submit" name="retrievePassword"/>
         <input type="hidden" name="lang" value="E"/>
         <c:if test="${retrivePassResult != null}">
             <c:out value="${retrivePassResult}"></c:out>
         </c:if>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should wrap your form in a div and call the dialog on the div.

```
<div id='dialog' style='display:none'>
<form action="UsersAccountServlet" id="retrievePasswordForm" method="post">
        <label>Email address</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" />
        <input type="submit" name="retrievePassword"/>
         <input type="hidden" name="lang" value="E"/>
         <c:if test="${retrivePassResult != null}">
             <c:out value="${retrivePassResult}"></c:out>
         </c:if>
    </form>
</div>
<span>Forgot your password? Click <a href="#" id="ForgetPassword">here</a> to retrieve it.</span>


  $("#ForgetPassword").click(function(){
     alert("here");
     $("#dialog").dialog();

 });
```

Look at the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/TUHgd/